# How to search for users which earned a high number of badges for a specific tag?

Tags: support, tag-badges

It could be interesting to be able to look for users which earned a high number of badges for a specific tag (such as java, asp.net-mvc, lisp, etc...).

With that possibility we could know which are the most expert users on a specific topic and gain insight by looking at the questions they answered.

Maybe it is already possible with search queries?

Comment: What do you mean by "badges for *a* specific tag"?

Comment: What do you plan to do with this information? Be aware when answering that there is no private messaging support of SOFUE **by design** because this is not a social network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click on Tags, click the tag. Click the "stats" tab, note the users in the "Last 30 days" and "All Time" lists.  I didn't think this warranted pictures :)